# What does "slash at" mean /@?

Tags: operators

I searched "slash at" as well as "/@" to no avail.

Consider

```
Normalize /@ A
```

I see the net effect, but what does /@ really mean? I understand that @ can be used in lieu of bracket [] for functional inputs. I understand /. is a replacement operator. But what is /@ ?

Comment: It is a shortcut for `Map` as you could discover by searching for `/@` in the documentation.

Comment: @SimonWoods. Thanks. I thought it didn't come up in the doc. Now I see it. My bad.

Comment: In general, [see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/29734).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the infix form of `Map` and takes each Element of the list `A` and applies it to `Normalize` in your case. The result is a List of the respective results.

See also: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html

```
f /@ {a, b, c, d, e}
(* {f[a] , f[b], f[c] , f[d] , f[e]}*)
```

Comment: It is the infix form of `Map`, as it is placed between the two operands.

Comment: you're right. I've corrected it. Thanks.